# UIKeyboard extra keys

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitextview, uikeyboard

I am looking for a way to add extra keys to a `UITextView`'s keyboard or add a `UIToolbar` above it.

How might I go about this?

**EDIT**

This is for an iPad app and if I was to add extra keys I would need a new row for them in the `UIKeyboard`.

Answer (score 1):

definitely check out this excellent tutorial on how to add extra keys to the keyboard.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html

its a really detailed solution and guides you every step of the way.

i've used this many a times. I hope that you can too.

Let me know if this helped you a lil.

Thanks

if you need any more help do let me know.

**PK**

Comment: That's definitely helpful, however it doesn't look like an actual key on the keyboard.

Comment: UIKeyboards contains a UIview that contains subviews for each key. So all we are doing is adding a subview to the keyboard view. which would still be a key. does this make sense?

Comment: I have also just tested the code in that tutorial and it doesn't work on iPad which I am targeting (sorry forgot to mention this in the question).

Comment: ok. please make the right changes in your post. thanks i will get back to you on this.